# Remove tar.gz file within bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am currently attempting to remove the oldest directory backups from another directory.  These backups are compressed using "tar -cpPzvf".  My simple question is if there is way to remove a tar.gz file using xargs and the "rm" commands

This is the line I am currently using:

```
sudo ls -t $BACKUPTARGET/adhoc/daily | tail -n +$NUMDAILY | xargs rm
```

The variables used are defined as:

- `$BACKUPTARGET`: points to "/backup"
- `$NUMDAILY`: This value is cut from a different configuration file that specifies the number of backups to be kept.

When I do run my script, the oldest backups except for a specified number are listed, but I get this error:

```
rm: cannot remove 'david-lenovo.etc.2016-12-07.20-10.tar.gz': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'david-lenovo.etc.2016-12-07.20-09.tar.gz': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'david-lenovo.etc.2016-12-07.20-04.tar.gz': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'david-lenovo.etc.2016-12-07.20-02.tar.gz': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'david-lenovo.etc.2016-12-07.19-54.tar.gz': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'david-lenovo.etc.2016-12-07.19-50.tar.gz': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'david-lenovo.etc.2016-12-07.19-49.tar.gz': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'david-lenovo.etc.2016-12-07.19-48.tar.gz': No such file or directory
```

I understand it might not be possible to delete tar.gz files without uncompressing them first, but I was curious as to if there was a way in order to make my script less complex.

Comment: Aside: do you realize that in your script, `rm` will run as the user that runs this command, and not necessarily `root`? The way you have it, only `ls` runs as root.

Comment: Also: "*it might not be possible to delete .tar.gz files without uncompressing*" -- poppycock! Of course you can delete them. They are perfectly ordinary files.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest change I can think to do is to change your working directory:

```
sudo ls -t $BACKUPTARGET/adhoc/daily | tail -n +$NUMDAILY | \
    ( cd $BACKUPTARGET/adhoc/daily && xargs rm ; )
```

Comment: I was unaware that one could remove these tar files.  I am a beginner when it comes to bash.  This command you showed me seems to work fine, but it isn't leaving the correct amount of backups.  It seems to leave only one each time when it should leave two because $NUMDAILY=2.  I also have an if statement that only processes the above line when the number of files is greater than the number of daily backups to keep.

Answer (score 0):

```
for single_file in "$(sudo ls -t $BACKUPTARGET/adhoc/daily | tail -n +$NUMDAILY)"
do
rm -rf $single_file
done
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> … tail -n +$NUMDAILY …
> ```
>
> This command you showed me seems to work fine, but it isn't leaving the correct amount of backups. It seems to leave only one each time when it should leave two because $NUMDAILY=2.

`tail -n +2` outputs lines starting with the 2nd; to leave two, you have to start from the third, e. g.:

```
rm `ls -t $BACKUPTARGET/adhoc/daily/*|tail -n+$((NUMDAILY+1))`
```